# Scrapy: Can't restart start_requests() properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, scrapy

I have a scraper that initiates two pages - one of them is the main page, and the other is a .js file which containt long and lat coordinates I need to extract, because I need them later in the parsing process. I want first to process the .js file, extract the coordinates, and then parse the main page and start crawling its links/parsing its items. 
For this purpose I am using the `priority` parameter in the `Request` method and I am saying that I want my .js page to be processed first. This works, but only around 70% of the time (must be due to the Scrapy's asynchronous requests). The rest 30% of the time I end up in my parse method trying to parse the .js long/lat coordinates, but having passed the main website page, so it's impossible to parse them.

For this reason, I tried to fix it this way:
when in `parse()` method, check which n-th url is that, if it is the first one and is not the .js one, restart the spider. However, when I restart the spider the next time it passes correctly the .js first, but after its processing the spider finished work and exits the script without an error as if it were completed.
Why is that happening, what is the difference with the processing of the pages when I restart the spider compared to when I just start it, and how can I fix this problem?

This is the code with sample outputs in both scenarios when I was trying to debug what is being executed and why it stops when being restarted.

```
class QuotesSpider(Spider):

    name = "bot"
    url_id = 0
    home_url = 'https://website.com'
    longitude = None
    latitude = None

    def __init__(self, cat=None):
        self.cat = cat.replace("-", " ")

    def start_requests(self):
        print ("Starting spider")
        self.start_urls = [
             self.home_url,
             self.home_url+'js-file-with-long-lat.js'
        ]
        for priority, url in enumerate(self.start_urls):
            print ("Processing", url)
            yield Request(url=url, priority=priority, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        print ("Inside parse")
        if self.url_id == 0 and response.url == self.home_url:
            self.alert("Loaded main page before long/lat page, restarting", False)
            for _ in self.start_requests():
                yield _
        else:
            print ("Everything is good, url id is", str(self.url_id))
            self.url_id +=1
            if self.longitude is None:
                for _ in self.parse_long_lat(response):
                    yield _
            else:
                print ("Calling parse cats")
                for cat in self.parse_cats(response):
                    yield cat

    def parse_long_lat(self, response):
        print ("called long lat")
        try:
            self.latitude = re.search('latitude:(\-?[0-9]{1,2}\.?[0-9]*)', 
            response.text).group(1)
            self.longitude = re.search('longitude:(\-?[0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]*)', 
            response.text).group(1)
            print ("Extracted coords")
            yield None
        except AttributeError as e:
            self.alert("\nCan't extract lat/long coordinates, store availability will not be parsed. ", False)
            yield None

    def parse_cats(self, response):           
        pass
        """ Parsing links code goes here """
```

Output when the spider starts correctly, gets first the .js page and second starts parsing the cats:

```
Starting spider
https://website.com
https://website.com/js-file-with-long-lat.js
Inside parse
Everything is good, url id is 0
called long lat
Extracted coords
Inside parse
Everything is good, url id is 1
Calling parse cats
```

And the script goes on and parses everything fine.
Output when the spider starts incorrectly, gets first the main page and restarts start_requests():

```
Starting spider
https://website.com
https://website.com/js-file-with-long-lat.js
Inside parse
Loaded main page before long/lat page, restarting
Starting spider
https://website.com
https://website.com/js-file-with-long-lat.js
Inside parse
Everything is good, url id is 0
called long lat
Extracted coords
```

And the script stops its execution without and error as if it were completed.

P.S. If this matters, I did mention that the processing URL in the `start_requests()` is processed reversed order, but I find this natural due the the loop sequence and I expect the `priority` param to do its job (as it does it most of the time and it should do it as per Scrapy's docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally handled it with a workaround:
I check what is the `response.url` received in `parse()` and based on that I send the further parsing to a corresponding method:

```
def start_requests(self):
        self.start_urls = [
            self.home_url,
            self.home_url + 'js-file-with-long-lat.js'
        ]
        for priority, url in enumerate(self.start_urls):
            yield Request(url=url, priority=priority, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    if response.url != self.home_url:
        for _ in self.parse_long_lat(response):
            yield _
    else:
        for cat in self.parse_cats(response):
            yield cat
```

Answer (score 1):

As to why your Spider doesn't continue in the "restarting" case; you probably run afoul of **duplicate requests** being filtered/dropped. Since the page has already been visited, Scrapy thinks it's done.
So you would have to re-send these requests with a `dont_filter=True` argument:

```py
for priority, url in enumerate(self.start_urls):
    print ("Processing", url)
    yield Request(url=url, dont_filter=True, priority=priority, callback=self.parse)
    #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  notice us forcing the Dupefilter to
    #                                        ignore duplicate requests to these pages
```

As to a better solution instead of this hacky approach, consider using `InitSpider` (for example, other methods exist). This guarantees your "initial" work got done and can be depended on.
(For some reason the class was never documented in the [Scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#generic-spiders), but it's a relatively simple `Spider` subclass: do some initial work, before starting the actual run.)

And here is a code-example for that:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider

class QuotesSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['website.com']
    start_urls = ['https://website.com']

    # Without this method override, InitSpider behaves like Spider.
    # This is used _instead of_ start_requests. (Do not override start_requests.)
    def init_request(self):
        # The last request that finishes the initialization needs
        # to have the `self.initialized()` method as callback.
        url = self.start_urls[0] + '/js-file-with-long-lat.js'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_long_lat, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_long_lat(self, response):
        """ The callback for our init request. """
        print ("called long lat")

        # do some work and maybe return stuff
        self.latitude = None
        self.longitude = None
        #yield stuff_here

        # Finally, start our run.
        return self.initialized()
        # Now we are "initialized", will process `start_urls`
        # and continue from there.

    def parse(self, response):
        print ("Inside parse")
        print ("Everything is good, do parse_cats stuff here")
```

which would result in output like this:

```
2019-01-10 20:36:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-01-10 20:36:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-01-10 20:36:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://127.0.0.1/js-file-with-long-lat.js> (referer: None)
called long lat
2019-01-10 20:36:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://127.0.0.1> (referer: http://127.0.0.1/js-file-with-long-lat.js/)
Inside parse
Everything is good, do parse_cats stuff here
2019-01-10 20:36:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into that, I may check out ```InitSpider```. I still don't understand if the reason is that Scrapy doesn't visit again the already visited URLs, why it still visits the first one and stops before the second one, the rule should apply in all cases IMO.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov, you can run the Spider with LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG" and then you should see, if you get a line about the `dupefilter` dropping your requests. I will try to clarify that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally managed to solve the issue with a workaround - making the requests synchronized. So first I parse the first page with parse(), then call the second from there and parse it subsequently, plus I verify the response.url is the correct one. I will keep your idea in mind and might apply it shall I again run into similar issue.

Comment: @NikolayShindarov, that does look like a better logic :) Feel free to write that as your answer and accept it (if mine doesn't fit), but please mark it as answered if it is.

Comment: Done. Sorry, my bad, it's not exactly as I described it to you, the ```parse()``` doesn't send the second ```Request```, you can look at the solution. Thanks again for your input.